# Can't update UI in main thread inside a dispatch queue swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar, alamofire

I am using Alamofire and SVProgressHUD for querying an API and process the data. 
The question is that inside the dispatchqueue, even if I update the UI in main thread, the result of update will come after the dispatch queue is done. 
 What I want to do is to display a progress status on progress bar and continuously update the progress status(float) in a loop. However, this won't appear until all the things in the dispatchqueue is done. My code looks like below.
Cheers

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async(execute: {
        Alamofire.request(queryURL).responseJSON() { response in
    //Do something
    for i in 0..<100{
        //Do lots of things
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            SVProgressHUD.showProgress(Float(i/100), status: "Loading...")
        }
    }
 //Dismiss
})
```

Comment: I don't think that cast to float is correct for integer division.. You are dividing two integers then casting the result to a float. An integer divided by an integer is an integer. Try something like: `Float(i) / Float(100.0)` instead and see if it works.

Comment: @Brandon Thx for your reply. I think that is not the issue. If I put my code like this inside the loop, the progress of 0.5 will only be shown after all the things done.                        DispatchQueue.main.async {                       //SVProgressHUD.showProgress(Float(featureID)/Float(featuresNum), status: "Loading...")
                            SVProgressHUD.showProgress(0.5, status: "Loading...")
                        }

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :-

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async(execute: {
    Alamofire.request(queryURL).responseJSON() { response in
    //Do something
    for i in 0..<100{
        //Do lots of things
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            SVProgressHUD.showProgress(Float(i)/100 as Float, status: "Loading...")
        }
    }
 //Dismiss
})
```

It will display like....

0.0
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.06
0.07
0.08
0.09
0.1
0.11
0.12
0.13
0.14
0.15
0.16
0.17
0.18
0.19
0.2
0.21
0.22
0.23
0.24
0.25
0.26
0.27
0.28
0.29
0.3
0.31
0.32
0.33
0.34
0.35
0.36
0.37
0.38
0.39
0.4
0.41
0.42
0.43
0.44
0.45
0.46
0.47
0.48
0.49
0.5
0.51
0.52
0.53
0.54
0.55
0.56
0.57
0.58
0.59
0.6
0.61
0.62
0.63
0.64
0.65
0.66
0.67
0.68
0.69
0.7
0.71
0.72
0.73
0.74
0.75
0.76
0.77
0.78
0.79
0.8
0.81
0.82
0.83
0.84
0.85
0.86
0.87
0.88
0.89
0.9
0.91
0.92
0.93
0.94
0.95
0.96
0.97
0.98
0.99

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of threads. You can find more on this bottom link. Ui only works on concurrent

[Click here on link to know more](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1)

Apple will not allow to change ui controls in thread. So you have to update ui outside thread.